# Broadcast message to all clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've tried broadcasting a message to all clients with no success.

The marked line **WORKS** but only to one client.

I've already tried these options:
socket.emit
socket.broadcast.emit

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `on` function on the wrong object. You should rename the `socket` variable to something else. Most commonly, people use `io`.

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Then, you will need to call `emit` on `sockets` to send to all users:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);
});
```

Of course, `send` is an `emit` that uses `message` as the event. So you can use it instead inside your callback:

```
io.sockets.send(data);
```

In either case, you then have to do the following in your client to react to this event:

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
  // Do things with data
});
```

Note: `socket.broadcast.emit` can be used to send an event to all users connected other than the user that just connected as the `socket`.